# Convert Windows-1252 xml file to UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, xmlencoder

Is there any approach to convert large XML file(500+MBs) from 'Windows-1252' encoding to 'UTF-8' encoding in java?

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

- Open a `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` with the Windows-1252 for the input
- Open a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` with the UTF-8 encoding for the output
- Create a buffer char array (e.g. 16K)
- Repeatedly read into the array and write however much has been written:

  ```
  char[] buffer = new char[16 * 1024];
  int charsRead;
  while ((charsRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      output.write(buffer, 0, charsRead);
  }
  ```
- Don't forget to close the output afterwards! (Otherwise there could be buffered data which never gets written to disk.)

Note that as it's XML, you may well need to manually change the XML declaration as well, as it *should* be specifying that it's in Windows-1252...

The fact that this works on a streaming basis means you don't need to worry about the size of the file - it only reads up to 16K characters in memory at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a one-off or a job that you need to run repeatedly and make efficient?

If it's a one-off, I don't see the need for Java coding. Just run the query ".", for example

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -s:input.xml -qs:. -o:output.xml
```

making sure you allocate say 3Gb of memory.

If you're doing it repeatedly and want a streamed approach, you have to choose between handling it as text (as Jon Skeet suggests) or as XML. The advantage of doing it as XML is primarily that the XML declaration will get taken care of, and character references will be converted to characters. The simplest is to use a JAXP identity transformation:

```
Source in = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
TransformerFactory f = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Result out = new StreamResult(new File("output.xml"));
f.newTransformer().transform(in, out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off, Java may not be the most appropriate tool. Consider [`iconv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv):

```
iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 <source.xml >target.xml
```

This has all the benefits of streaming without requiring you to write any code.

Unlike Michael's solution, this won't take care of the XML declaration. Edit this manually if necessary or, now you're using UTF-8, omit it.